# Formatting dates with only month and year in R

Tags: r, date

I have quite a simple problem that I've not found anywhere on here.

I have date format:

```
times = c("Dec_2011" , "July_2011", "Dec_2010"  ,"July_2010" , "Dec_2009" , "July_2009", "Dec_2008" ,
                     "July_2008" ,"Dec_2007" , "July_2007", "Dec_2006" , "July_2006" ,"Dec_2005" , "July_2005",
                     "Dec_2004" , "July_2004" ,"Dec_2003" , "July_2003", "Dec_2002" , "July_2002", "Dec_2001" ,
                     "July_2001", "Dec_2000" , "July_2000")
```

How can I get these into date format:

```
31-07-2000, 31-07-2001, etc...
31-12-2000, 31-12-2001, etc...
```

I've tried:

```
times <- format(as.Date(time, "%B_%Y")
times
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA


times <- format(as.Date(time, "%B_%Y), "31-%m-%Y)
times
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

times <- as.Date(paste("31", times, sep="-"), "%d-%m-%Y")
times
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

times <- format(as.Date(time, "%b_%Y"), "31-%m-%Y")
# NA
```

I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need `31` as the day for all the elements, use `paste` to join 31, convert to `Date` class and get the desired format with `format`.

```
format(as.Date(paste(times, "31", sep="_"), "%b_%Y_%d"), "%d-%m-%Y")
#[1] "31-12-2011" "31-07-2011" "31-12-2010" "31-07-2010" "31-12-2009" "31-07-2009" "31-12-2008" "31-07-2008" "31-12-2007" "31-07-2007" "31-12-2006"
#[12] "31-07-2006" "31-12-2005" "31-07-2005" "31-12-2004" "31-07-2004" "31-12-2003" "31-07-2003" "31-12-2002" "31-07-2002" "31-12-2001" "31-07-2001"
#[23] "31-12-2000" "31-07-2000"
```

Instead of manually `paste`ing 31, we can automate this with `as.yearmon` from `zoo`.  The advantage is that for months that have less than 31 days, we get the last day by doing that.

```
library(zoo)
format(as.Date(as.yearmon(times, "%b_%Y"), frac=1), "%d-%m-%Y")
#[1] "31-12-2011" "31-07-2011" "31-12-2010" "31-07-2010" "31-12-2009" "31-07-2009" "31-12-2008" "31-07-2008" "31-12-2007" "31-07-2007" "31-12-2006"
#[12] "31-07-2006" "31-12-2005" "31-07-2005" "31-12-2004" "31-07-2004" "31-12-2003" "31-07-2003" "31-12-2002" "31-07-2002" "31-12-2001" "31-07-2001"
#[23] "31-12-2000" "31-07-2000"
```